# Draw stroke on Openlayers map

Tags: draw, openlayers-3

I'm aware of the standard draw methods offered by Openlayers 3 but miss the option to draw a continuous stroke. ol.interaction.Draw specifies the type as [ol.geom.GeometryType](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.geom.html#.GeometryType), but I can't find any possibility to draw a stroke instead of one 'Point' after another.

For sure I could use standard canvas drawing methods but I'd like a solution which is independent from the map renderer. Any ideas on how to archive that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to draw a LineString?

Comment: right, that was the answer. I didn't have figured out the GeometryType LineString. thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freehand drawing of lines and polygons was added in 3.5 - hold the shift key while dragging to activate it.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/draw-features.html

You can activate freehand drawing by default like that:

```
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: drawLayerSource,
    type: 'LineString',
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
```